# How to fix CORS Error fix Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angular, iis, cors

I'm trying to learn Angular by building a solution which communicates with an IIS Server running on PHP as an API.

The IIS runs with Windows Authentication to identify the user. The IIS/PHP combination works.

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
```

A direct call of this prints out my domain\username

For angular i was following this guide -> https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Angular:

```
this.courses$ = this.http
      .get<Course[]>("https://my_server/test.php",{ withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(
        map(data => _.values(data)),
        tap(console.log)
      )
```

This produces a CORS Error, visible in the DevTools.

[image]

With `"withCredentials: false"` it seems to work, but because of the missing credentials i'm getting a '401 Unauthorized'.

[image]

How can I fix the Angular part for making a request to 'my_server' which works with the Windows Authentication from the IIS?

Comment: It wasn't me, but we need to see the specific details of the CORS error. There should be a more detailed error message.

Comment: Did you install CORS module on IIS?

Comment: thanks for the hint with the cors error, since there was no more text then the one seen in the picture above, i've used some js in the console to trigger the cors error with an xhr call, which led me in return to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and thanks to the helpful comments, i've found a solution.

There was no more text as seen in the picture above, so i've used the console to generate a new call

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://my_server/test.php', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

Which led to the following error message

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my_server/test.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

which in return led to the following page:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246313/how-to-add-multiple-url-to-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-sharepoint-2013

and after removing the original `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and same editing in the web.config, it now looks like this

```
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?my_server|(.+\.)?localhost:4200" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

the important part here is `(.+\.)?localhost:4200`